# Can you set the encoding of the Edit control to UTF-8 in Windows API?

Tags: winapi

The Edit control have an encoding of UTF-16 when using Unicode, but can the encoding be changed to UTF-8?

Comment: Not really... Windows 10 has an option now to be able to set the language for non-Unicode programs to UTF-8, but it is beta. If you want to build a portable program, I think the answer is no. It's not too difficult to use MultiByteToWideChar() or WideCharToMultiByte() to do the conversions using the CP_UTF8 code page when you want to put or retrieve text from a Unicode edit control

Comment: newer versions of windows also have a manifest option that enables the same, so even if the system setting is not  enabled it will work on a per-process basis.

Comment: You cannot change the encoding of the EDIT control. It will *always* store its content using UTF-16LE internally. You *might* be able to change the character encoding at the interface, but you cannot change the interpretation of your data at the interface for a single EDIT control. It's a global per-application setting (plus a global system-level setting). With that out of the way, what *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable I want to load some text that are UTF-8 encoded into an Edit control in my program.

Comment: The answer to that problem is [MultiByteToWideChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar).

Comment: @user8437463 Is [Rich Edit Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/rich-edit-controls) fine for you? It supports more features like set code page to UTF-8 [(`SF_USECODEPAGE`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamout).